# MySQL / PHP storing a formula

Tags: php, mysql, eval

The dilemma:

I have options that need to store pricing data.

Each option can have a different formula to determine it's cost.

E.g., one option's total cost will be cost * sq feet, but another option will be cost * perimeter feet, while another option still will simply be a fixed cost.

These options are being pulled from the database by several sites that my company owns.

Each one of those sites needs to be able to calculate the options pricing in the exact same way.

We currently have PHP code on each site that pulls data from the database, and then determines how to calculate it.

The problem with this method is that we will sometimes change how a price is calculated, and when that happens, we have to edit the pricing module repository and then update it to each server that hosts one of these sites.

I'm looking for a better solution.

I'm toying with the idea of storing a formula in the option record in the database, then each site would simply need to call the option, apply data to the formula stored there, and then run the formula.

Now, this can be done with `eval()`, but I don't really want to do it that way.

Eval example to give you a clearer idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
$product->width = 3;
$product->length = 4;
$formula = $option->cost_formula; // $product->width * $product->length * $option->cost
eval($formula);
```

Does anyone else have any other solution?

Comment: `include()` and `eval()` pass code largely to the same PHP runtime functions. Just the source differs. No need for stigmata. Maintainability should be a consideration. If code distributed via the database seems an issue, you could as well `rsync` or `svn update` your code onto multiple servers. (Your example formula is simplistic enough to allow for parameterized calculations however.)

Comment: Just check this [http://www.website55.com/php-mysql/2010/04/how-to-calculate-strings-with-php.html](http://www.website55.com/php-mysql/2010/04/how-to-calculate-strings-with-php.html)

Comment: @Hawili That presents the same eval security issues without the flexibility.

Comment: did you find a solution - i've got the exact same situation.

Comment: No. In the end, I built my own parser to interpret and calculate the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html).

Pseudo-code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculation1 (@cost decimal(6,2), @feet int)
RETURNS decimal(7,2)
AS
BEGIN
    --Other formula calculations
    RETURN @cost * @feet
END
```

You would then call the function from your query: `SELECT calculation1('1.50', 15)...`

This way you can update any changes to your function and queries using the function will produce the same result.

Comment: +1 for an awesome idea, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Something crucial in my example above is that I have a model built from a db record, but then manipulated and not saved to the db yet.

So I would either have to calculate the proper data, e.g. sq feet or perimeter feet, before calling the function or I would have to pass in an array or an object. Calculating the proper data defeats the purpose, and I'm pretty sure you can't pass an object or an array to MySQL.

Comment: @njk If I could pass in an object or an array, then I could have each option call it's function and pass a data set to that function. Then the function can calculate the proper data. However, without the use of an object or an array, I would have to set up each function with different parameters, and then determine which parameters need to be passed.

Comment: @story I think that you may be able to get away with a more generic function

Comment: @story I would need the PHP code/logic for where you pull data from the database and determine how to calculate it.

Comment: @njk Nah, I've looked this thing over in detail. This is a great answer, but still doesn't do quite what I need. Thanks for the time and effort, though.